# Unable To Kill Jar File Started with Python Subprocess

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I've got a python script here which downloads a jar file from github, executes it, waits for 3 minutes and is supposed to kill the process.

Note that this works perfectly fine on windows, but somehow the script is not doing what I need it to do on Ubuntu. The jar file indeed does what I need it to do, however after that, the python script does not continue.

To summarise, nothing after `p2 = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "serverstarter-2.0.1.jar", "&"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)` gets run. Not even `time.sleep(180)`.

So what I am trying to figure out is why executing the jar file within the script seemingly "stalls" the script.

Note that another python script calls this script in this way `subprocess.run(["python3", p, "&"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)`.

Here is the code:

```
wget.download("https://github.com/AllTheMods/alltheservers/releases/download/2.0.1/serverstarter-2.0.1.jar", bar=None)

p1 = subprocess.run(["chmod", "+x", "serverstarter-2.0.1.jar"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

p2 = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "serverstarter-2.0.1.jar", "&"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
time.sleep(180)
p2.kill()

try:
    log_files = glob(src + "**/*.log")
    for files in map(str, log_files):
        os.remove(files)

    zip_files = glob(src + "**/*.zip")
    for files in map(str, zip_files):
        os.remove(files)

    startserver_files = glob(src + "**/startserver.*")
    for files in map(str, startserver_files):
        os.remove(files)

    serverstarter_files = glob(src + "**/serverstarter*.*")
    for files in map(str, serverstarter_files):
        os.remove(files)

    files_to_move = glob(src + "**/*")
    for files in map(str, files_to_move):
        shutil.move(files, dest)

    time.sleep(20)

    forge_jar_file = glob(dest + "forge-*.jar")
    for files in map(str, forge_jar_file):
        print(files)
    os.rename(files, "{}{}".format(dest, "atm6.jar"))

except Exception as e:
        post_to_slack(f"Error occured in {os.path.basename(__file__)}! {e}")

quit()
```

Comment: `&` is not an argument you can pass on an argv vector. It's shell syntax. It's irrelevant when there is no shell, and there's no reason to use it here at all (the `subprocess` module doesn't do an implicit `wait()` on `Popen` object creation, which is the shell behavior that `&` turns off; if you _wanted_ a `wait()`, you'd typically use `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.run()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`).

Comment: To get the same bug in an interactive shell that you get with the above Python, you can run `java -jar serverstarter-2.0.1.jar '&'` -- the quotes around the `&` make it a literal argument instead of syntax, so you can inspect what your program really does when passed that argument.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to do a `chmod` here. If you _did_ need it you could do it with native Python (using the `os` module), but you don't need it: `java -jar some.jar` doesn't need `some.jar` to be executable just as `python file.py` doesn't require `file.py` to be executable.

Comment: BTW -- it would make this a stronger question if you described _how you know_ that `time.sleep()` isn't being run. If the real problem is something like the connection between your debugger and your Python code being disrupted, f/e, we need to know what debugger you're using to have a chance at diagnosing it. (That's actually not a completely random guess -- if your Java program is inheriting and sending data over the file descriptor used for communication between the IDE you're using and the program you're running, that's an easy way for the IDE to lose all ability to inspect the program).

Comment: ...assuming that you _are_ using a debugger, one of the things I would do is to _stop_ using it, and switch to something simpler -- like `python -m trace yourscript.py` -- at least long enough to rule out problems with that debugger itself.

Comment: Also, `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` is a bad idea while debugging -- you generally want as many details as you can get.

Comment: After adding a couple of `post_to_slack()` statements. Seems like I found out that the script is stalling after `time.sleep(180)`, having waited much more than 180 seconds, with a `post_to_slack()` statement before and after it. 

Now I am not exactly sure why this is the case.

Comment: Have you gone the `python -m trace` route yet? That said, you might keep an eye on your system load -- if the Java program is trying to use more RAM than you actually have, swapping pages to and from disk can keep things busy enough to prevent other processes from being scheduled in a timely manner.

Comment: (if the only way you have to monitor your service is through messages posted to Slack, you have bigger problems -- you can't tell if your program exited because the OOM killer killed it, or if it got an error rather than an exception, or if anything else outside the expected code flow happened. When debugging, you _really_ want hands-and-eyes on the execution environment; typically, that means being ssh'd in).

Answer (score 0):

If you on Linux, Type this on terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep -i java
```

and check the process ID of your jar file and then kill it using pkill command.

Comment: The OP is trying to figure out how to fix their code to not have this problem; not how to work around the problem after it happens.

Comment: This solution is to expansive and may kill any running Java process . There could be many.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from kill method documentation:

https://pythontic.com/multiprocessing/process/kill

> When invoked kill() uses SIGKILL and terminates the process.
> When SIGKILL is used, the process does not know it has been issued a > SIGKILL. The process cannot do any cleanup. The process is killed
> immediately.Remember, though miniscule it takes a finite time to kill the process.

Not all process respond to SIGKILL !!!!

Suggesting to kill **ALL** processes having argument `serverstarter-2.0.1.jar` in the command.

Like this:

```
  pkill -9 -f "serverstarter-2.0.1.jar"
```

If cannot kill **ALL** processes having argument `serverstarter-2.0.1.jar` . You need to save the PID of the created process  after creation time and kill it.